# Convert import path to file path ('conf.settings' -> conf/settings.py)

Tags: python

I would like to convert the import path to file path.

I can check the OS and replace '.' with either '\' or '/' and suffix with '.py` sure - but I'm interested in a built in way.

`importlib.util.find_spec('conf.settings').origin` does not suit my needs because that imports the module and returns the entry from `sys.modules`, and I'm writing a static analysis tool that does not import the code, just parses it.

Comment: I am curious too. Did you have a look at how other linters do it? pylint, isort or black come to mind.

Comment: I don't think you're using the term "static" or "statically" properly — so don't understand your question.

Comment: static meaning "static analysis", like pylint does. Examining source code without executing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>from astroid.modutils import file_from_modpath
>>>file_from_modpath(['conf', 'settings'])
/tmp/project/conf/settings.py
```